# class library for asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net, oracle

We are going to develop many small applications using asp.net (c#) with oracle database. I would like to write a simple class library say dataaccess.dll that has most of the functionality for connecting to database, executing a sql query, update or insert or delete etc so that i could reuse them in my many small projects. Is there a good example online somewhere that i can get started from?

Well, probably i didnt explain my question properly..
I am not looking for how to make asp.net connect to oracle or how to execute a query (throught odp.net) from asp.net .

I am looking for ways to construct a class library with methods such as connect(),executeQuery(),insert(),update(),delete() methods which would accept connectionstring,sql query text etc as parameters from any c# program. What i want is a generalized dataaccess code or guideline to develop one based on odp.net that i can reuse again and again.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Tons. Be sure you're looking at ODP.net http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search around for **ODP.net** which is what you'll be using. This is a helpful search term, but you'll find a lot of examples for your specific needs.

Look for pages that explain how to set up your classes to use the connector such as http://ergemp.blogspot.com/2008/10/querying-oracle-with-c-and-odpnet.html

Make sure to pay attention to the type of objects you're using to select data and don't confuse `SqlDataSource` with `OracleConnection`.

Look for pages detailing the use of the Oracle client, `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`.

You may know most of this, but in case someone find this question and doesn't, they get some info.